# trying to iterate over a url in python facing message error

Tags: python, json, api, loops

I am trying to fetch the data from an API by selectively taking the json data output I am getting and append it into list. However I am iterating over dates in the format YYYY-MM-DD as required by API to fetch data

For some dates I get no error but message.

```
{'generated_at': '2018-04-05T06:41:30+00:00',
 'message': 'No events scheduled for this date.',
 'schema': ''}
```

How can I pass this as a exception in try and except to continue looping since it is not an error.

Also I am unable to iterate completely the date and month values as the input should be in MM and DD but in python3 I can assign value = 0i
 such as

m = 03 so I have to assign it as only m = 3

d  = 02 so I have to assign it as only d = 2

Here is my code - python3.5.2 - ubuntu 16.04
complete code

```
import requests
import json
import urllib.request
import pprint
m = 0
d = 0
g = []
final = []
```

loops

```
for i in range(1,9,1):
    for j in range(1,9,1):
        m = i
        d = j


        url = "http://api.sportradar.us/cricket-t2/en/schedules/2017-0{0}-0{0}/schedule.json?api_key=vpkypw2wdypr2ujfmt8n526g".format(m,d)

        response = requests.request("GET",url)

        resp = response.json()

        a = resp['sport_events']
        s = []

   #looping through  json output received 
        for i in range(len(a)):
        s.append(a[i]['competitors'])
        gm = s[0]

        final.append(gm)

print(final)
```

I want to know how to iterate for all the numbers starting from 01 to 31 and how to use try and except for the message I receieve for data not present.

Answer (score 1):

First point: instead of blindly assuming there *will* be a "sport_events" key in the response data, just check what you really have. Your `resp` variable is a plain python dict, which api is very extensively documented.

Also you should wrap the request in a try/except (HTTP requests can very easily fail...) and check the response status code before the `response.json()` call (and wrap this call in another try/except - it's not garanteed to succeed even with a 200 status code and an application/json content type in the response).

Second point: don't build your dates from integers and string formatting, use the stdlib's `datetime` module instead (or some 3rd part wrapper around it like [dateutil](https://dateutil.readthedocs.io/en/stable/)) and a `strftime()` call to format the date object to string.

As a side note, this:

```
for i in range(len(a)):
    s.append(a[i]['competitors'])
```

is the uselessly complicated way to write:

```
for item in a:
    s.append(item['competitors'])
```

which itself can be rewritten as:

```
s = [item["competitor"] for item in a]
```

but I wonder why you bother building this list since you only use it's first item, so you could as well replace this:

```
    s = []
   #looping through  json output received 
    for i in range(len(a)):
        s.append(a[i]['competitors'])
    gm = s[0]
```

with:

```
    gm = a[0]["competitor"]
```

Answer (score -1):

url="http://api.sportradar.us/cricket-t2/en/schedules/2017-0"+m+"-0"+d+"/schedule.json?api_key=vpkypw2wdypr2ujfmt8n526g"

should work.

Answer (score -1):

or you can first convert m to text and add a 0 depending on the number and then concat to url.